# More options menu does not show the options

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to implement more options menu in mobile app and I am using react-native-options-menu package from react-native. Even though I click on the more options button the menu doesn't show up. Below is the code that I have used.

```
{<OptionsMenu
                customButton={(<Icon type = {iconNames.fontAwesome} name={iconNames.more} color={"white"} size={30} style={{marginRight: 8}}/>)}
                destructiveIndex={1}
                options={["Edit", "Delete", "Cancel"]}
                actions={[this.editPost, this.deletePost]}/>}
```

PS: I don't know what I am missing or doing wrong. Also, in the import statement (import OptionsMenu from "react-native-options-menu") it shows 3 dots below react-native and when I hover over it, it says cannot find module, but the module is present in node-modules

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using a named import, try to import without braces, import OptionsMenu from "react-native-options-menu";

Comment: I was previously using without braces, it still didn't work.